# Model validation with two attributes in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to add model validation and in this case specifically to a email property in the model. I have added the required attribute with a error message but I also need to validate that the input is an email:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Foodbrain.Globalization.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName="EnterEmail")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Foodbrain.Globalization.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailInvalid")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

I get an error:

```
Antingen ErrorMessageString eller ErrorMessageResourceName måste anges, men inte både.
```

This means that I need to specify one of theese but not both at once.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an explicit defintion for `ErrorMessage = null` for both attributes, like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Foodbrain.Globalization.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName="EnterEmail", ErrorMessage = null)]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Foodbrain.Globalization.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailInvalid", ErrorMessage = null)]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

By the way, I'm pretty sure that the error you are seeing is not due to the use of two separate validation attributes, but rather is a .NET 'bug' that requires explicitly setting `ErrorMessage = null`.  The message is misleading.

Comment: Thank you, you were completely correct and your solution works fine, thank you David.